# Como ordenar e listar apenas 5 itens de uma lista?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, foreach, visual-studio-2017

veja bem, eu estou desenvolvendo o dashboard de um sistema web, em um dos filtros eu devo listar os 5 principais clientes e ordena-los por valor mais alto das somas de totais de notas fiscais emitidas. Eu já estou conseguindo listar tranquilamente, o problema é que o filtro está listando tudo (quando que deveria apenas listar 5) e está de forma desordenada. Segue abaixo o meu código:

```
public ActionResult Index()

        {
            var dashboard = new DashboardViewModel();


                var lista = new List<NotaFiscal>();


            var participantes = db.Participantes
                          .ToList();
            var notas = db.NotasFiscais
                          .ToList();

            foreach (var part in participantes)
            {
                var x = new NotaFiscal();
                var res = notas.Where(y => y.ClienteID == part.ParticipanteId).Sum(o => o.ValorTotalNota);
                x.ClienteID = part.ParticipanteId;
                x.ValorTotalNota = res;
                x.NomeCliente = part.NomeParticipante;
                lista.Add(x);
            }


            dashboard.NotasFiscais = lista;
            dashboard.NotasFiscais.Take(5).OrderByDescending(x => x.ValorTotalNota);
            return View(dashboard);
        }
```

Alguém saberia me apontar a solução para que esse filtro liste apenas os 5 registros com os valores maiores de notas fiscais?

Abaixo o Jean e o Filipe me deram alternativas, após fazer o sugerido em ambos os casos ocorrem o seguinte erro, veja a imagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

O filtro foi feito mas não foi atribuído novamente onde deveria

Você pode fazer assim:

```
dashboard.NotasFiscais = lista.Take(5).OrderByDescending(x => x.ValorTotalNota);
return View(dashboard);
```

E dá pra mudar um pouco o código por conta das consultas, já que quando um toList é feito, a consulta é executada e isso pode afetar performance do que você estiver implementando.

Aqui um exemplo de como pode ficar:

```
var dashboard = new DashboardViewModel();


var lista = dbParticipantes
    .Select(e => new NotaFiscal {  
        ClienteID = e.ParticipanteId,
        ValorTotalNota = e.NotasFiscais.Sum(n => n.ValorTotalNota)
    })
    .OrderByDescending(e => e.ValorTotalNota)
    .Take(5);

dashboard.NotasFiscais = lista;
return View(dashboard);
```

Comment: Então amigo, muito obrigado mais da forma que vc pontuou eu me deparo com o seguinte problemas: Não é possível converter implicitamente tipo "System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable<Ebase.EmissorNFeWeb.Models.NotaFiscal>" em "System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<Ebase.EmissorNFeWeb.Models.NotaFiscal>". Existe uma conversão explícita (há uma conversão ausente?)
Dai como eu resolveria isso agora????

Comment: E a segunda forma que vc cita não é possível, pois eu tenho que passar pelo foreach de qualquer maneira!!

Comment: Veja o erro, editei a pergunta com o anexo

Comment: @WPfan tenta dar colocar assim `dashboard.NotasFiscais = lista.ToList();`

Comment: Filipe, até que daria certo sim, mais a função que você fez ai contém um erro, nessa linha não consigo recuperar o NotasFiscais: `ValorTotalNota = e.NotasFiscais.Sum(n => n.ValorTotalNota)`

Comment: @WPfan qual erro dá?

Comment: Esse erro ai: "Participantes" não contém uma definição para "NotasFiscais" e não foi possível encontrar nenhum método de extensão "NotasFiscais" que aceite um primeiro argumento do tipo "Participantes" (há uma diretiva de uso ou referência de assembly ausente?)

Comment: @WPfan tem como colocar na pergunta tuas entidades? Pensei que no mapeamento Participante tinha uma lista de NotaFiscal.

Comment: Não adianta eu passar pra você a entidade, ela tem mais de 20 campos e n tem nenhum NotasFiscais nele, entendeu?

Comment: @WPfan entendo, então tem que fazer no caminho contrário mesmo, usando a nota fiscal. Quando e tiver um tempo, tento fazer aqui

Comment: E ai Filipe, tu consegue demostrar ai o exemplo da forma que citou no último comentário??? Fico aguardando para ver se vai da certo aqui!

Answer (score 2):

## Explicação

O problema do seu código que não ordena conforme o esperado está no trecho abaixo:

```
 dashboard.NotasFiscais.Take(5).OrderByDescending(x => x.ValorTotalNota);
```

Podemos ver que antes da ordenação, você seleciona cinco registros através do método `Take(5)`. Para que funcione corretamente, altere a order para a exemplificada abaixo:

```
dashboard.NotasFiscais.OrderByDescending(x => x.ValorTotalNota).Take(5);
```

## Sugestão

Altere este bloco de código:

```
   foreach (var part in participantes)
            {
                var x = new NotaFiscal();
                var res = notas.Where(y => y.ClienteID == part.ParticipanteId).Sum(o => o.ValorTotalNota);
                x.ClienteID = part.ParticipanteId;
                x.ValorTotalNota = res;
                x.NomeCliente = part.NomeParticipante;
                lista.Add(x);
            }
```

Para este:

```
var lista = db.NotasFiscais
                 .Where(x => db.Participantes.Any(y => y.ParticipanteID == x.ClienteID))
                 .GroupBy(z => z.ClienteID)
                 .Select(x => new NotaFiscal(){
                        ClienteID = x.First().ClienteID,
                        ValorTotalNota = x.Sum(n => n.ValorTotalNota)
                  })
                 .OrderByDescending(x => x.ValorTotalNota)
                 .Take(5)
                 .ToList();

dashboard.NotasFiscais = lista;
return View(dashboard);
```

<sub>Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/4Y8IDf)</sub>

Comment: Jean, no meu caso eu segui o seu exemplo e continuo deparando com o mesmo problema relatado anteriormente, quando é feito 'dashboard.NotasFiscais = lista;' da Não é possível converter implicitamente tipo "System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable<Ebase.EmissorNFeWeb.Models.NotaFiscal>" em "System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<Ebase.EmissorNFeWeb.Models.NotaFiscal>". Existe uma conversão explícita (há uma conversão ausente?)

Comment: E vc cita que o problema de não ordenar corretamente é devido a isso aqui: dashboard.NotasFiscais.Take(5).OrderByDescending(x => x.ValorTotalNota); mais não, porque anteriormente eu tinha feito do jeito que você colocou abaixo e tava desordenado da mesma forma

Comment: editei a pergunta com o anexo do erro, veja lá, do jeito que vc sugeriu

Comment: Fiz uma alteração, adicione um ToList() ao final do novo trecho de código.