# Como fazer esse FOR (em C#) listar apenas os cinco primeiros itens?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, for

Tenho uma lista ordenada, que eu preciso exibir apenas os 5 primeiros itens, e não todos os registros do banco, portanto não estou conseguindo. Aqui meu código como está:

```
public class DashboardController : Controller
    {
        private NFeWebContext db = new NFeWebContext();
        // GET: Dashboard
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var dashboard = new DashboardViewModel();
            var lista = new List<NotaFiscal>();
            var participantes = db.Participantes
                              .ToList();
            var notas = db.NotasFiscais
                          .ToList();

            foreach (var part in participantes)
            {
                var x = new NotaFiscal();
                var res = notas.Where(y => y.ClienteID == part.ParticipanteId).Sum(o => o.ValorTotalNota);
                x.ClienteID = part.ParticipanteId;
                x.ValorTotalNota = res;
                x.NomeCliente = part.NomeParticipante;
                lista.Add(x);

            }

            dashboard.NotasFiscais = lista.OrderByDescending(x => x.ValorTotalNota).ToList();

            for (var i= 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                lista.ToList();
            }

            return View(dashboard);



        }
    }
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como ordenar e listar apenas 5 itens de uma lista?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/301671/como-ordenar-e-listar-apenas-5-itens-de-uma-lista)

Comment: o contexto é o mesmo mais a dúvida é diferente!

Comment: está escrito "Possível", se for duplicada sua pergunta é fechada, se não for, nada acontece ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existe o método `Take` onde vc pode passar um parâmetro que é a quantidade de registros que sera retornado da lista;
Como comentado pelo Virgilio.

`lista.Take(5).ToList().;`

Utilizando o `Take` antes do `ToList` você evita o carregamento na memoria de toda a lista;

Editando para seu código:

```
dashboard.NotasFiscais = lista.OrderByDescending(x => x.ValorTotalNota).Take(5).ToList();
```

Assim eliminando o seu ultimo For

```
   for (var i= 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                lista.ToList();
            }
```

Comment: `ToList().Take(5)` causa o carregamento total da tabela depois em mémoria pega 5, é melhor `lista.Take(5).ToList()` ???

Comment: Sim, melhor seria utilizar Take(5).ToList(); Obrigado pela correção.